# Show that a polynomial is linearly independent or independent, help? Beginner in linear algebra here.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have 5 questions where it is asking to prove (I don't know anything about proofs, never took a class in them) for each of them, if the polynomial list is linearly independent or dpeendent or not.

```
1) 1, x, x^3,
2) 1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5
3) x^2 + 2x + 3, x^2 - x, 3x^2 + x + 1, 2x^2 + 1,
4) 1 - x, 1 + x
```

**Can anyone please first explain the general concept of linear independence in this problem and how to apply it to see whether not a polynomial is independent or not?**

I also forgot a lot about polynonials and am struggling with how linear combinations apply to polymnomials. It would be greatly helpful if you could explain and then apply it to just one.

I'll figure out the rest.

Comment: If you don't understand a concept then you should ask a direct question about that concept. Explaining that you lack confidence in your understanding is not the same as showing effort towards the problem

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of *linearly dependent*. We say that polynomials $p_1(x),\ldots,p_n(x)$ are linearly dependent if there exist coefficients $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, not all zero, such that $$c_1p_1(x)+\cdots+c_np_n(x)=\bf0.$$ I'm using the bold zero, $\bf0$, to indicate the "zero polynomial", not just the number zero. An equivalent way of writing this equation would be $$c_1p_1(x)+\cdots+c_np_n(x)=0\quad \text{for all}\ x\in\Bbb R.$$

Here's an example of linearly dependent polynomials:
$$p_1(x) = x+1\\
p_2(x) = x+2\\
p_3(x) = 3x+5
$$
Notice that $p_3(x) = p_1(x)+2p_2(x)$. From a certain point of view, $p_3$ is redundant: if you wanted $3x+5$, you could make it yourself by a combination of $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Now look at your first example, $\{1,x,x^3\}$. Can you find constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that
$$c_1+c_2x+c_3x^3=0$$
for *all* $x\in\Bbb R$? If you could, it would have to be true for $x=0$, for example. Substituting $x=0$, we see that $c_1=0$. But it would also have to be true for $x=1$; you can substitute this to get another equation. You can also substitute $x=2$, $x=-1$, and whatever other values you like. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at $4)$.  S'pose we have $a(1+x)+b(1-x)=0$.  Then $a+b=0$ and $a-b=0$.  Thus $a=b=-b\implies a=b=0$.  Thus $1+x$ and $1-x$ are linearly independent.

The others are done in just the same way.

I can tell you just by looking at them that $1)$ and $2)$ are yes.

As for $3)$, it's no, because there are four polynomials and the space is three dimensional.

Comment: I can tell you just by looking at them that 1) and 2) are yes.

Can you explain why and please be elaborate? how do you determine if they are linearly independent or not and if you were asked to show your work, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: and can you please explain why 3 is not linearly indepedent?? what the hell, what do you mean by space is 3 dimensional and there's 4 polynomials? if the list is specificed as r^4, would you be incorrect? in this case it said nothing at all, how do you know it's linearly dependent? what does the degreee of the polynomial have to do with anything wtf?

Comment: For $3)$, they are all polynomials of degree two.  The space of such polynomials is known to have dimension three.  For the first and second, it's just something I know.  You can set it up the way I did number four.  Then use the fact, essentially the fundamental theorem of algebra (FTA), that a polynomial equals zero if and only if the coeffecients are all zero.

Comment: 'For the first and second, it's just something I know' this all i needed to read to understand nothing u say would actually help me... but thanks?

Comment: Here's $1)$:  suppose you have a linear combination of them equal to zero.  So $a\cdot1+bx+cx^3=0$.  Then by FTA, the  coeffs are all zero.  That is, $a=b=c=0$.  So it's almost immediate.